# Basic authenticator with Netty

Tags: java, authentication, netty, packet

Actually for my server game I'm not using Netty. I've created a socket multithreaded system for send packet object who is serialized into and deserialized from (Int and Out)StreamBuffer.

I've discovered Netty and I think it's better to use it for my network system.
I've actually created a Client and Server handler (both extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter) to serialized and deserialized my packet from the ByteBuf, it's work FINE :) !

Now I want migrate my authentication system.
Actually, I've two Handler, the LoginHandler which can receive and process only the Login Packet (defined by an id when I send a buffer packet), and the ServerHandler which can receive and process all others packets.

### Actual algorithme

- Client side :

  1. User launch a client a new window ask him to enter his username and password When he click on "Login", the client connect to the server, and after send a LoginPacket.
  2. If a AuthServerPacket is sent by the server with the auth flag to true, he continue and open all others features.
  3. If a AuthServerPacket is sent by the server with the auth flag to false, it display a popup with the reason, and re-open the window login.
- Server side :

  1. When a user is connecting to the server it's the LoginHandler which is attached to the client.
  2. In this LoginHandler, only LoginPacket is processed, so, when it receive a LoginPacket it check the informations in a database, if these are correct, the client are added to the ServerHandler and deleted from the LoginHandler, and now he can receive and send all others packets.
  3. ServerHandler send a AuthServerPacket with auth flag to true.

My question is, what is the best way to re-create this system with Netty ?

I don't know if I can add the login handler in the pipeline which it will be not check it if a channel is authentified. I don't know how or if the process is stopped if one of the handler reject the channel.

Someone can help me to understand what is the best way to do what I want with Netty ?

Thanks you in advance for your answers.
Programmatically, beaucoralk.

Answer (score 3):

we talked on IRC #netty today :)

My suggestion is:

- In your Pipeline Initializer, always add the LoginHandler
- Once Login is successful, then the LoginHandler should:

  `ctx.pipeline.addAfter(this, "gameHandler", new GameLogicHandler());
  ctx.pipeline.remove(this);`

So basically your LoginHandler removes itself, after a successful authentication. Important: add the *new* Handler before removing the *old* Handler. :)

best regards

Comment: These are no method was appropriate with addAfter. I've used addLast.

Answer (score 2):

I've solved my problem with this :

- In my Pipeline Initialize always add the LoginHandler (don't add my ServerHandler)
- Once Login is successful, then the LoginHandler do :
  `ctx.pipeline.addLast(new GameLogicServerHandler());
  ctx.pipeline.remove(this);`

In fact I have not succeeded to use the addAfter like said Franz Bettag, no method was appropriate.

But thanks you to Bettag who help me to understand many things on #netty IRC.